# Define global function inside anonymous closure function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Is there any way to define within closure a global function? I would like to define one global function so I can call it with onclick event.

```
(function(){

 var private = 'private msg';

 function myprivate() {
   alert(private)
 }

 function wanttobeglobal() {
   alert(global) 
 }

})();
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very bad practice, but the only way short of declaring the variable outside the initial closure is to implicitly create a global variable.

```
wanttobeglobal = function() {
  alert(global);
};
```

The better way, if you can modify code outside of the closure, is with `var`:

```
var wanttobeglobal;

(function() {
  // ...
  wanttobeglobal = function() {
    alert(global);
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the function to `window`:

```
(function(){

 var private = 'private msg';

 function myprivate() {
   alert(private)
 }

 window.wanttobeglobal = function wanttobeglobal() {
   alert(global) 
 }

})();
```